# jsf2 flash is living longer that it should?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, flash-scope

What i use:
RichFaces version v.4.1.0.Final
Mojarra 2.0.3

*edit:  i installed mojarra 2.1.11*

So, im facing 2 problems.

1 - I'm going by flash, an object to see it in the next view. The problem is that when a re direct my page through the faces-config, the object never comes. When what i do is

```
Company companyToView = (Company)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("publicProfileCompany");
```

I get nothing. This should not happen since before re directing to the new .xhtml i set value.
How i set

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("publicProfileCompany", record.getContactedCompany());
  return "goToPublicProfile";
```

2 - And in other pages, after the object is inserted in the flash its lives longer than one redirect. In one case its lives 6 times longer!

I would like to put code, but the post would be to long.
If its needed i do it.

Answer (score 2):

Mojarra 2.0.3 is a rather old version. It dates from 1 july 2010. That's over 2 years ago already! Older Mojarra versions are known to have exactly this flash scope related problems, which is reported by among others [issue 1751](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1751).

Upgrade it to [Mojarra 2.0.9 or 2.1.11](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) (the currently latest Mojarra 2.0 and 2.1) and your most flash scope related problems should disappear. There's only one specific flash scope related problem left: it won't work when you redirect to a page in a different path (folder), but it should work when you redirect to a page in the same path (folder).

Comment: omfg, thx! the shit is coming from the fodlers then. I will try that and tell.

Regards.

Comment: well, i installed mojarra 2.1.11 and im still facing the same issue. My object in flash is living more than what it should

Comment: atm, i wasnt able to install 0.9 so after i do this i will comment about the solution. Regards